# Steam isn't working

Tags: steam

I'm very inexperienced with computers and new to Linux. I'm trying to load Steam but this message keeps popping up:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I don't know what to do, need someone to describe it to me in layman's terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try `env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam`
If that doesn't work make sure your actually on a 64-bit system, and download the correct version.
If that **STILL** doesn't work then try running:

```
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

IF IT STILL DOESN'T WORK (unlikely):

```
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```